# Can't unlock the folders that I locked with 'Folder Lock' program

Tags: windows-8, security

I use Folder Lock Version 5.2.6

**Problem** : It asks for new password each time I open it.

**Bigger Problem** : I had locked many folders with this software when it was working fine.
But now I can't access those folders anymore, they're still locked but software doesn't show these folders in its "locked folders list".
How do I unlock them?
The software was working fine for few months - I was able to lock and unlock things in my computer during that period. But all of a sudden the software Folder Lock just got reset somehow.

**Things I've Tried** :

- Locking the locked folder again, but the software Folder Lock turns up and asks for new password over and again.
- Looking in the security tab of the properties of the locked folder, but what I see is: *The security information you requested is either unavailable or can't be displayed*.

OS : Windows 8 Pro

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried to uninstall the software but it can't be done. Sure, I can simply delete it from program files, but I don't think that's gonna unlock those folders.

Comment: Have you tried Add/Remove the software, in Control Panel?

Comment: @Kevdog777 Yes, it says that the software can be removed form the main program after providing it the correct password. I have tried that too, and nothing happens when I click the uninstall button in options menu of the software.

Comment: Is there a way you can say "Forgot Password" or "Reset Password"?

Comment: @Kevdog777 The thing is, it does not ask for password, it wants me to set a new password each time I run it. It is assuming that it is its first run on the computer, each time when I run it. And there is no option for Forgot/Reset Password.

Answer (score 4):

Check if this helps:

- To remove password

  1. First close Folder lock and show hidden file and System hidden file
  2. Select the Tools menu and click Folder Options
  3. Select the View Tab

Under the Hidden files and folders heading select "Show hidden files and folders"

Uncheck the "Hide protected operating system files (recommended)" option

Click `Apply` then `OK`

Delete "win_mpwd_sys.dat" From

```
C:\ProgramData
C:\Users\Vortex\AppData\Local 
C:\Windows\ (in Windows x86) 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ (in Windows x64)
```

Run Folder Lock and enter new Password

Here is a link you may want to read, it is the [FAQ's](http://www.newsoftwares.net/folderlock/faq#Q6) for Folder Lock.

Comment: I couldnot find this file anywhere, after enabling hidden files, and system files too.

Comment: OK, well have a read through the FAQ's and see if that helps at all.

Comment: I have gone through the entire FAQ's and I have found that maybe I can unlock those files by installing the later version of folder lock, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was not able to retrieve my locked files but uninstall of folder lock without password is easily done by using for example speed commander (select folder lock from program files via speed commander and delete) Simple as that.(no password required) Can also be done with other file finding software as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to change the name of the parent directory in which the locked folder exists for example `Pictures` is the locked folder then change `C:/Anything/Pictures` to `C:/Anything else/Pictures`

If you don't have a parent directory in between you can change the name of the disk (except for `C` ) to any other like `D:` to `P:` or etc. the following shows how to change disk drive letters.

To change, add, or remove a drive letter

1. Open Computer Management by clicking the `Start` button Picture of the Start button, clicking `Control Panel`, clicking `System and Security`, clicking `Administrative Tools`, and then double-clicking `Computer Management`.  Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
2. In the left pane, click `Disk Management`.
3. Right-click the drive that you want to change, and then click `Change Drive Letter and Paths.`
4. Do one of the following:

   - To assign a drive letter if one has not already been assigned, click `Add`, click the letter that you want to use, and then click `OK`.
   - To change a drive letter, click `Change`, click `Assign the following drive letter`, click the letter that you want to use, and then click `OK`.
   - To remove a drive letter, click `Remove`, and then click `Yes` to confirm that you want to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Now Folder lock 7.6.0 updated software resolve this issue here: http://www.newsoftwares.net/folderlock/?id=uq