# How to unlock the locked drive in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-unlocking

I installed Folder Lock 7.2.2 and locked F drive, But now I can't access the F Drive.

It is not asking for the password. My system OS - Windows 7 64bit. How to unlock the F drive?

Comment: does the f drive doesnt show in folder lock list?execute folder lock and explore whether it shows there or absent there too?

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/598584/cant-unlock-the-folders-that-i-locked-with-folder-lock-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this helps:

- To remove password

  1. First close Folder lock and show hidden file and System hidden file
  2. Select the Tools menu and click Folder Options
  3. Select the View Tab

Under the Hidden files and folders heading select "Show hidden files and folders"

Uncheck the "Hide protected operating system files (recommended)" option

Click `Apply` then `OK`

Delete "win_mpwd_sys.dat" From

```
C:\ProgramData
C:\Users\Vortex\AppData\Local 
C:\Windows\ (in Windows x86) 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ (in Windows x64)
```

Run Folder Lock and enter new Password

Here is a link you may want to read, it is the [FAQ's](http://www.newsoftwares.net/folderlock/faq#Q6) for Folder Lock.

And last but not the least you can Open FolderLock with the **Serial Key** you used at the time of **installation**. It helps

Comment: If it's so easy to clear the password or apply a new one, then why would anyone even use that tool in the first place?

Comment: @Mario i.e is the drawback, every program has its own drawback

Answer (score 2):

You can only unlock the drive if you remember the password. Unlocking goes in the same way as locking. If you lost the password, your only option is to format the drive, as you cannot recover the files in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I got all my data from the D: drive just by changing the path, making D: to R:.  How to do it is described in this [Microsoft link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-add-remove-drive-letter#1TC=windows-7).

> **To change, add, or remove a drive letter**
>
> Open Computer Management by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security, clicking Administrative Tools, and then double-clicking Computer Management.  Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
>
> In the left pane, click Disk Management.
>
> Right-click the drive that you want to change, and then click Change Drive Letter and Paths.
>
> Do one of the following:
>
> To assign a drive letter if one has not already been assigned, click Add, click the letter that you want to use, and then click OK.
>
> To change a drive letter, click Change, click Assign the following drive letter, click the letter that you want to use, and then click OK.
>
> To remove a drive letter, click Remove, and then click Yes to confirm that you want to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Folder Lock FAQs](https://www.newsoftwares.net/folderlock/faq/#faqs_4):

> Q4. I have forgotten my Master Password. How can I get it back?
>
> If you ever forget your master password, you can still use the **Serial Number** that you have **used to register Folder Lock** as the **master key**. Important: Please note that this feature **only works** if you have kept the **Master Key option enabled in Password Security settings**. Folder Lock has been developed to provide the most comprehensive and robust defense against any data-theft threat. One of the key defense features the application provides is removing any backdoors to this protection, which includes maintain password lists. Unfortunately, if you have forgotten your password, and if you have not been able to set the use of the Master Key in Password Security settings,YOU WILL NOT BE ABLE TO PERFORM MAJOR APPLICATION FUNCTIONS, like LOCK FILES, UNINSTALLING APPLICATION AND SETTING CONTROLS FROM THE PROGRAM SECURITY OPTIONS IN SETTINGS! (depending on user settings) Please make sure that you remember your password at ALL times or keep it in a safe place.

Comment: This looks like it's from something like the program's user manual?  That's great, but the "Q4" is sort of a head scratcher.  Could you edit your answer to identify the source at the beginning of the answer?  That will provide some context and maybe a place to go for further reading.  BTW, when you paste information from a source document, you can use the block quote symbol above the edit box, which will also clue people in as to what they're looking at.  Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

To regain your data stored in Folder Lock do this:

1. Go to My computer
2. Select the view tab, then show hidden files
3. then go to c directory
4. Then go to user/user name/appdata/local
5. then this will be a file name extension as (.dat)
6. cut that and paste to the desktop
7. Enjoy.. folder lock is asking for new password